# How to use a variable that has been initialized in the for loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am a beginner in Android studio. So do pardon me if I do make any mistakes!
I am trying to use a variable String myKey outside of the for loop so that the Intent won't be looped inside the for loop as well. I am trying to move the code circled in blue outside of the For Loop, but due to the String myKey, I am unable to do so! Any Help will be greatly appreciated

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
 protected final void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
                Point[] p = barcode.cornerPoints;
                 database.orderByChild("barcode").equalTo(barcode.displayValue).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String myKey = objSnapshot.getKey();
                            Toast.makeText(Inventory.this, myKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             Intent intent = new Intent(Inventory.this,Edit.class);
                             intent.putExtra("value", myKey);
                             startActivity(intent);

                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before moving to making android applications you should learn basic programming and then experiment with it and learn OS philosophies, generate context about application development. In short, this thing is not for you for this moment. This is a long way journey you should not skip anyting in between. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable globally otherwise before loop.

```
protected final void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
        if (data != null) {
            String myKey="";
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
            Point[] p = barcode.cornerPoints;
             database.orderByChild("barcode").equalTo(barcode.displayValue).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        myKey = objSnapshot.getKey();
                        Toast.makeText(Inventory.this, myKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Inventory.this,Edit.class);
                   intent.putExtra("value", myKey);
                   startActivity(intent);

                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable before the for loop so that you can use it after the loop.

```
String myKey = null;
for (/**/){
    ...
    //update myKey
    myKey = objSnapshot.getKey();
}
//use myKey
intent.putExtra("value", myKey);
```